# Application not picking up /usr/local/bin path executables

Tags: ruby, apache, path, centos

- Application Framework: Ruby on Rails
- Web server: Apache
- Web App Server: Phusion Passenger
- Operating System: Centos 7
- Instance is hosted on AWS

We are coming across a issue where the application is not able to pick up the executables from `/usr/local/bin` path. This is the default path where all compiled software package executables are available.

The catch here is the application does work fine until some point in time. This issue occurs abruptly and to fix it we are creating a softlink for specific executable from /usr/local/bin path to /usr/bin path.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Passenger invokes Rails using daemon user, Not sure how to find the path of daemon user as it does not have a shell. From which user does daemon user inherit the shell. Is there anyway I can check the PATH variable for daemon user

Comment: Before you launch your command, log the PATH variable in your logs. That way you will know if it's changing or not.

Comment: See here on how to ensure environment variables on Passenger apps: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/environment_variables.html#passenger-served-apps

Comment: However it's weird that it works for some time, and then not. Therefore I would log PATH each time before you call `system`, or whichever way you launch your executables. I don't know why, but perhaps something is modifying PATH during your operation.